# How to programmatically set views format?

Tags: 7, views

On install I'm trying to set my `commerce_products` view from table to list. Where and how do I do this? I also need to add a class to the list.

I'm a Drupal noob so if answers could be detailed that would be appreciated.

Comment: You can try to go to your view's edit page and export it. In export window you can see view's code. There you can see $handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'table'; - there format will be stored. For more info from us you should provide more info from yourself.

Comment: Thats exactly what I need, but then where in my theme files do I add this line so this is set when theme is installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comments it sounds like you want to change the style_plugin from your theme.  You need to implement hook_views_default_views_alter() in your theme.

Something like this:

```
function themename_views_default_views_alter(&$views) {
 if (isset($views['commerce_products']) {
  $views['commerce_products']->display['default']->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'table';
 }
}
```

I'm not too familiar with commerce so you might not want to target the default display if that display is used elsewhere; you might just want to target the 'page' display.